# Setting the (http)status code (to something other than 500) after an exception in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

As the title implies I want to change the http status after an exception occured. 
The short background is that to be able to show an error page I need to send a status code of 200 to the client. (On error status codes it dumps the data and shows a generic error popup)

To test this I have:

```
    @RequestMapping(value= "/err")
    public String throwError()
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

---

In web-xml:

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage</location>
    </error-page>
```

---

And the errorPage controller (gets called)

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/errorPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String errorPage(HttpServletResponse response, Model model, Locale locale ) {
        int errorStatus = response.getStatus();
        response.reset();
        model.addAttribute("errorStatus", errorStatus);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
        LOGGER.debug("---------->" + response.getStatus());
        return "errorPage";
    }
```

---

The catalina log output is 200 BUT the response in the client is:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Somewhere Spring encodes the exception as a statuscode 500 (I suppose it is in the HandlerExceptionResolver chain?) and then my errorPage controller is called.
Spring seems to remember that an exception was thrown and ignores (or recodes?) the status code to 500 after the controller returns.

The confusing (or maybe not?) thing is that if I return a Response Entity from the errorPage controller and set the status code this will be honored. Eg:

```
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

I suppose that this is not a bug but a feature and that Spring knows better than me and I should really change my way of implementing this whole thing. (!!?)

I cannot return just a ResponseEntity since I need to render the error page. I suppose I could if I streched myself render the page in the controller and put it into the ResponseEntity to achieve what I want but it just seems ... wrong.

There must be a way of controlling what status code is returned other than returning a ResponseEntity (and bypassing whatever mechanism is resetting it to 500). Or just telling the framework not to re encode the thrown exception as a status code 500.

To be complete I have tried setting the statuscode in a HandlerExceptionResolver and returning a ModelAndView with the same disappointing result. (500)
I have also tried @ControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandler .. same result..

Any clues to what happens after returning from the controller (or HandlerExceptionResolver) that sets the status code and how I can disable it?
Maybe it is some unknown setting in my configuration that causes this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set status code by using the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/err")
public String throwError()
{
     throw new IllegalStateException(message,
                         errorCode);
}
```

Comment: Hi Akhil and thanks for answering.

I think you may have misunderstood my question?
The IllegalStateException is just an example, for testing the functionality. The exceptions could be thrown by any code anywhere in the app for any number of reasons (it is not controlled by me).

... But that said do you mean that Spring somehow evaluates the cause of the exception and sets the status code to 500 if it is null? That could be plausible, but as I said I can't change all the potentially exception throwing code ...

Comment: Maybe I could catch the exception and rethrow another custom one... like exceptionHandledReturnOKException, and set the @ResponseStatus in the new exception... thanks for the idea, I will try it!

Comment: No ... NOTHING seems to work!
I find this surprising .. that such basic requirement as exception handling is so messy and confusing in Spring and on top of that also not fully working.
Or am I missing something?

I am down to extending the DispatcherServlet and catch the exceptions there and do a redirect to my error page.. but this seems so tacky.. but  well I'm out of options...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, using a custom HandlerExceptionResolver. I spent an afternoon digging in the source code. As far as I can tell, this is because of Tomcat's error page handling.

If you look at the source code for org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable() (Tomcat 7), you'll see that this method overwrites the status code attribute with 500:

```
request.setAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, Integer.valueOf(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
```

This handler is executed for all exception-based error pages.

My workaround is dorky. You can **reset the response status code in the error page** (assuming it's a JSP). Adding this line at the top of your (JSP) error page should work:

```
 <% response.setStatus(200); %>
```

If you need to use a custom status code, you can set it in the controller:

```
 request.setAttribute("myStatusCode", statusCode);
```

then read it back in the JSP:

```
 <% response.setStatus(Integer.valueOf(request.getAttribute("myStatusCode").toString())); %>
```

but that's, like, even dorkier...

I tried to remove the exception request attribute in the controller, which should trigger the status-code based error handling in Tomcat's valve:

```
request.removeAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with Spring's DispatcherServlet: processHandlerException() re-sets all the missing error attributes after calling the exception resolver (why?!?), thus forcing the throwable() handler in the valve, thus ignoring the custom status code...

Hope this helps.